# Quartz, ensure completion of two jobs before starting another

Tags: c#, listener, quartz-scheduler, jobs, quartz.net

I am using the quartz framework and i was wondering if there  is a way to ensure that two jobs have completed successfully before running a third job.

One further catch, the only stipulation of a completed job is that an error is not thrown. In my two "parent" jobs, there are a bunch of checks that exit early if a file is not yet available or something like that. So if it completes this way, then Quartz assumes that everything went smoothly but in fact it did not. I am persisting data in the datamap, with flags that indicate if the program needs to run or not. I am wondering if i can access those datamaps upon completion, and if both jobs' datamaps contain a value saying it was run successfully, then launching a different program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017396/Running-jobs-sequentially-using-Quartz-Net-with-th here is whwere i finally found the answer.